# Can't get height of div to adjust

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in a pickle.

[I'm working on a layout](http://featherystylesheets.tumblr.com), and I need the main div to adjust to the window size, *mainly* to get that middle div to make a scrollbar upon resizing. It's acting as a table cell currently, which is why it's forcing itself to simply become taller instead of using a scrollbar. It's in a containing div in the efforts to keep from doing this though.

```
<div id="ALL">
    <div id="VOLTRON">
        <div id="MAINSIDEBAR">ok</div>
        <div id="CONTENT">
            <div id="TICKER">please</div>
            <div class="WRAP">
                <div id="POSTSGOHERE">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
                </div>

                <div id="RIGHTSIDEBAR">WELL THEN.</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I resorted to Jquery, and though I found a code for this very thing, it's not working.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('#ALL') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#ALL') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried setting a max height, I've tried setting it to vh instead of percent, I've tried containing it, and I feel like I've exhausted a pretty decent amount of time on this conundrum myself to finally get help.

[Here is the entire code](http://pastebin.com/MeYfFMFS), in case that also helps. I'm certain that the *way* I'm doing this is the reason it's not working.

So, any idea for a fix for this? And why what I'm trying isn't working?

**EDIT:** I need to specify this again: I want the entire "table" to only fit the window, but the purple div is the one that should scroll. The problem is, though I've set it to `overflow-y: scroll;` it just changes the size of the entire container. The entire table just grows past the window to compensate for the overflow.

Comment: try max height and a bit of js

Comment: have a look inside developer tools and see that the height is actually being set correctly; your code looks flawless to me: http://jsfiddle.net/E9zVd/

Comment: ...you just don't see it as it's exactly the size of the window... you may want to make it smaller to see it (subtract some of it?)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, you just don't see it as it takes the exact size of the window. You would see it better if you subtracted a little off of it and added the `overflow-y:scroll` to `#ALL` instead of the container:

```css
#ALL {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#ALL').css('height', $(window).height()-50 + 'px');
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#ALL').css('height', $(window).height()-50 + 'px');
    });
});
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E9zVd/1/)**

**EDITED**: Following your edit, and I know this would threw off your layout completely, but the only thing that worked for me, if you wanted the purple one to move only, was to remove the table-cell display and set the height to the container instead of ALL, and adding the scroll only to that:

```css
#ALL {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#POSTSGOHERE {
    background-color: purple;
    max-height: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#POSTSGOHERE').css('height', $(window).height()-50 + 'px');
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#POSTSGOHERE').css('height', $(window).height()-50 + 'px');
    });
});
```

**[I updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E9zVd/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Keep the max-height and set

```
overflow:scroll;
```

This should do the trick.

**PS: Also try adding it to the Wrap class.**

Answer (score 0):

You think to display the #all div as an iframe style in fullscreen?

like here:
[You can check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyFDE/1/)

You were just missed one line of CSS.

```
#all 
   overflow: scroll
```

SASS syntax

NOTE: pls use small letter div selectors dont use capital ones, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might work better

Place the window height in a var
so the div can read it, and rewrite the var when the user resizes

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var heightt = $(window).height();
        $('#ALL').css('height',heightt);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var heightt = $(window).height();
            $('#ALL').css('height',heightt);
        });
    });
```